# Dynamically call parameters using concat(), select element name

Tags: variables, xslt, xpath, parameters, xslt-2.0

I want to dynamically call parameters in a template based on another paramaters value, something like:

Let's say I have a list of Values that are dermined in several ways:

```
<xsl:param name="One"/>
<xsl:param name="Two"/>
<xsl:param name="Three"/>
```

from which I'd like to create matching elements from such as:

```
<One>1111</One>
<Two>2222</Two>
<Three>3333</Three>
```

Instead of creating all of the elements individually I like to create a seperate template or function to do that.

I was attempting something like:

```
<xsl:template name="AddElement">
  <xsl:param name="Name" select="/foo/bar/text()"/>
  ...
  <xsl:variable name="Value" select="concat('$', $Name)"/>
  <xsl:element name="$ElementName">
    <xsl:value-of select="$Value"/>
  </xsl:element>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

I want to avoid doing that multiple times the same way:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($One) != 0">
  <One>
    <xsl:value-of select="$One"/>
  </One>
</xsl:when>
```

Ideally it could just be

```
<xsl:call-template name="AddElement">
  <xsl:with-param name="ElementName">One</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: The example is not clear. If you have a list of values, you can easily use `xsl:for-each` to create an element for each value. The exact code depends on the format of the list.

Comment: How is `$ElementName` declared? Iterating over a sequence to output elements with dynamic names is very simple. To match elements names dynamically against a sequence of string or QName (in XSLT 2.0) is also a common task. Using a map data type in XSLT 1-2 involves node-set manipulation of some XML instance with user defined schema. In XSLT 3 there is already a built in map data type.

Comment: If you could use XSLT 3.0, here's how you could do it using a map; http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNL/1

Comment: And if you can't use XSLT 3.0, you could do something like this... http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNL/2

Answer (score 1):

I think Change following Code:-

```
<xsl:element name="{$ElementName}">
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't construct variable references (or other XPath expressions) dynamically as strings and then evaluate them. XSLT isn't a macro language.

In XSLT 3.0 you could put the data in a map and select dynamically from the map. I tried to put together an example for you, but I really couldn't get to the bottom of what your hypothetical code was trying to achieve.

Comment: I think this would be an example of using maps (assuming the `Name` variable literally contains the name of the parameter whose value is required): http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuNL

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I have an XSLT which main work is done by determining the correct value for each parameter at the end I basically just want all the parameters and their values to be put in to elements of their own name. instead of using the same writing the element name and pulling the value I wanted an abstract template/function for all of them together.

Comment: @ffranziiska It would be better if you post an input sample with desired output, otherwise we are trying to guess if you need any of the simple task I just commented under your question or you need dynamic XPath evaluation.